# How to read specific sheet with multiple columns with readmatrix in matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab

so I am trying to read multiple sheets in excel using matlab by this function:

```
Data_mat=readmatrix('DATA_I.xlsx');
```

I tried a couple of things using additional info, bu seems not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be a matrix, use that command. On the other hand, if you want to read tables (considering the column name), you can use the readtable command.

I generated a dummy excel file that only contains 2 sheets with some numbers there. If you want to read the matrices, use the readmatrix, or if you want tables, just change that function to readtable. Both functions have the same argument structure.

```
% Define the file name
FileName = "MatrixesInFile.xlsx";
% Get the sheets in the excel file
Sheets = sheetnames(FileName);

% Generate the variable with the matrices
myMatrices = struct;
% Read the matrices and store it in the struct
for n=1:length(Sheets)
    % Get evaluated sheet
    eval_sheet = Sheets{n};
    % Get the matrix
    values = readmatrix(FileName,'Sheet',eval_sheet);
    % Create a field in the struct and store the matrix there
    myMatrices.(eval_sheet) = values;
end

% Print the variable
myMatrices
```